# How to use assert statement in Katalon Studio?

Tags: katalon-studio

Can someone tell me please how to use an assert statement in Katalon Studio?

The scenario is- I have to create one user (user=program), once I click the submit button I have to capture the result if the user is created successfully or not. If the user is created successfully, only then the execution should proceed further if not then the test case should fail and further execution should stop.

Please let me how to use assert statement in Test Case, Object repository or global variable or keywords?

[image]

Comment: How can a normal user (not a computer) know that the user is created successfully? Is there a message shown?

Answer (score 1):

In **Katalon Studio**, default assertions are available. Using which we can keep the validation check points. Please refer to below code *where its checking for userPofileImge element*. *If user profile img present, assertion will be PASSED and execution will* continue, *or else failed and execution stops*.

```
**Code Snippet**

  assert WebUI.verifyElementVisible(findTestObject('HomePageLocators/userProfileImg')) == true : 'login failed as user profile is not present'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Groovy language with Katalon studio, this is the answer:

```
def x = 1
assert x == 2
```

> // Output:              // // Assertion failed: // assert x == 2 //
>   | | //        1 false

Groovy Language features: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-testing-guide.html#_introduction

Comment: @Priyanka; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

**Katalon Studio** has significant customized assert methods. You can choose as per your requirement and control failure. In your case, when you click on Submit, user is created and probably you get alert message, notification message and or new user should be visible in user area.
So you have to identify checkpoint from above and get the property and WebUI.verify--select method with FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE.

Katalon Studio provides mutiple way to handle test failure

```
       FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE
       FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE        // Applicable in your case
         FailureHandling.OPTIONAL
```

Code will be like this

```
   WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('User Locator'), maxWaitTime, 
   FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)   // use this if you want to fail further       
   execution
```